# How to make Mysql database to support Arabic Language?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to save Arabic language in mysql database but it doesnot save in Arabic format. 
It shows question marks instead of Arabic. How to make it store values in Arabic.

I tried many queries seeing from internet but it doesnot changes. How to change it for Arabic.
  "ar_SA: Arabic - Saudi Arabia"
Please suggest a way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use UTF-8 in the page's encoding, in the database connection, and the database itself.

Answer (score 7):

i use WAMP Server. (windows,apache,mysql,php).

//so important

FIRST :

in phpmyadmin or MySQL : 
make sure that Mysql Database is utf.
make sure that the your database and it's tables are utf-general-ci

after connecting to Mysql immidiately (before choosing your DB) make this order.

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

example :

```
<?php
     //connect to MySQL
     mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
     mysql_set_charset('utf8'); // that's the order.
     echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";

     //connect to your DB
     mysql_select_db("mydb") or die(mysql_error());
     echo "Connected to Database";
?>
```

SECOND : 
in the meta data in the php file make the meta data as following :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Third : 
Make sure that the php file it self is utf-8 enabled . u can make sure in your IDE settings , or if u work on notepad++ or Komodo Edit then u can find it in the status bar at the bottom of the window , right side.

// i tried this but it didn't have effect.

in the header of the php file (before every thing).

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

in the form submitted:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your database encoding and collation is utf8_general_ci