# UTF-8 Access PDO PHP Arabic accdb

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I'm facing a problem with PDO & Access using PHP 
I have this code :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO work (".implode(",",array_keys($_POST)).") VALUES('".implode("','",$_POST)."')";
                                try{

                                $dbNew = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=".$dbA."; Uid=; Pwd=;charset=UTF8");
                                $queryaa = $dbNew->prepare($query);
                                $inst = $queryaa->execute();
                                } catch(PDOExepction $e){
                                echo $e->getMessage();
                                }
```

when i insert data to a MYSQL database , it gets saved correctly like : 
[Correct Form Of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukyEq.png)

But when i insert to Access database , it gets saved incorrectly as you can see here :

[Incorrect Form of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TScev.png)

So , how can i solve this problem?

Comment: go through the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229593/how-to-make-mysql-database-to-support-arabic-language

Comment: @KarthikeyanVivekanandhan I Already checked that , but how do i use UTF-8 for an Access Database?